# Risky Connection message

Tags: short-connections, ewr

Scheduled to arrive in EWR (New York/Newark N.J) at 7:49a.m. on a Saturday morning with no weather issues expected. Connection leaves at 8:30a.m.. Itinerary states Terminal change and Risky connection. Spoke with Rep and was advised that there should be enough time, but did offer the option to change. Any recommendation?

Comment: If the airline has marked it as a risky connection and has offered to change your booking, I would look into the alternative they are offering.

Comment: Weather is far from the only concern when making connections in New York; congestion is often as big a problem, though not so much in the morning and on a Saturday.

Answer (score 4):

If this is a *single* ticket, it is up to the airline to rebook you if you miss the second flight. For many destinations (e.g. Chicago, Denver), flights are frequent and you won't have to wait long.

It would also help if you clarify whether "agent" is an airline agent or a travel agent.